# when ajax false in jquery-mobile. Why loader image not working at form submit in android default browser

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, jquery-mobile-loader

when ajax false in jquery-mobile. Why loader image not working at form submit in android default browser. I tried this code.

My Jquery Code for mobile website

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});


$("form").validate({
        rules: {
            phone: { required:true,minlength: 10, maxlength:10 },
            zip: { required:true,minlength: 5, maxlength:5 },
            first_name:{required:true,lettersonly:true,minlength: 2},
            address:{required:true,minlength: 2, maxlength:200},
            last_name:{required:true,lettersonly:true,minlength: 2},
            email:{required:true,email:true}
        },
        errorElement:'div',
        errorClass: "warning",

        submitHandler: function(){

            $.mobile.loading( 'show' );
            form.submit();

            }

    });
```

Comment: because ajax is set to false. Image loader is a part of jQM Ajax navigation system.

Comment: When ajax is off, link is loaded via HTTP not jQM's _Ajax_.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code for show loader
$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", LOADING_MSG, false);


For Hide use this
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();



$.mobile.loading( "show", {
        text: msgText,
        textVisible: textVisible,
        theme: theme,
        textonly: textonly,
        html: html
});
Hide Msg
$.mobile.loading( "hide" );
```

`

Comment: this wont work when `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` and `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` is deprecated. Use `$.mobile.loading('show / hide')`.

Comment: which version of JM you are using?

Comment: I use 1.3.1 version of JM.